# Can't get contact form to center for responsive css

Tags: html, css

I have looked online and tried different things to make the contact form be centered when the screen is or gets smaller. The header and navbar are responsive, the contact form is not. Also, my code was in two separate sheets on here and then the website randomly combined them. You can break them apart if you know how.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'arial', serif;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #ffb6c1;
  color: #ffffff list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

img {
  max-width: auto max-height: auto;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.nav>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #C0C0C0
}

.banner {
  width: 100;
  display: block;
}

.banner>.bannerimage {
  width: 100;
  height: 100;
  display: block;
}

ul.nav {
  margin: 0;
}

.cognito {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Events.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contactusmobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 900px)">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img class="banner-image" src="ccc.png" width="100%" height="150px">
  </div>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="Menu.html">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="entertowin.html">Enter to Win</a></li>
    <li><a href="Merchandise.html">Merchandise</a></li>
    <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <style>
    .cognito {
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-left: 450px;
    }
    
    body {
      background: url('heartcoffee.jpeg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 2000px 1000px;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="cognito">
    <script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/s/q8sF4QFeokuqNI1bQZm3vg">
    </script>
    <script>
      Cognito.load("forms", {
        id: "1"
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Put this in a jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

It’s useless post all code of your problem request.
However, for center a form inside a div container you can use:

```
.center{
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Else inside a **position:relative;** container:

```
.center{
position:absolute;
left:50%;
transform:translateX(-50%);
top:0;
}
```

Comment: I posted my html and css.

Comment: Try to create a codepen of your issue, have you fixed?

Comment: Yes, I want to center the div class cognito.